# Basic 2D path finding (no graph needed)

Tags: java, game-physics

I am working on a game (just for my own fun) in Processing (a variant of Java), and have run into a problem.  I have a projectile class that is created and managed by a Castle class, and it goes towards an Enemy class (which is a moving target).  What I am trying to do (conceptually) is make this projectile find its intended target (Euclidian distance), say its 20 units away, and move 5 units along that line (i.e. 1/4 of the way there).  My problem is that I don't know how to extract the x and y components of that vector to update this projectile's position.  Here is my projectile class currently:

```
class Projectile{

  private PImage sprite;
  private Enemy target;
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private int speed;

  public Projectile(PImage s, Enemy t, int startx, int starty, int sp) throws NullPointerException{
    if(t == null){
      if(debug){
        println("Null target given to Projectile(), throwing exception");
      }
      throw new java.lang.NullPointerException("The target of the projectile is null");
    }
    sprite = s;
    target = t;
    x = startx;
    y = starty;
    speed = sp;
    if(debug){
      println("Projectile created: " + t + " starting at position: " + startx + " " + starty);
    }
  }


  public void update(){
    if(target != null){
      int goingToX = target.getCenterX() ;
      int goingToY = target.getCenterY();

      //find the total distance to the target
      float d = dist(this.x, this.y, target.getCenterX(), target.getCenterY());
      //divide it by the velocity vector
      d /= speed;

      //get the dx and dy components of the vector



    }else{//target is null, i.e. already destroyed by something else
      //destroy this projectile
      //if the higher functions were correct, then nothing needs to go here
      //this should be deleted as long as it checks for this.hitTarget()
      return;
    }
  }

  public void render(){
    image(sprite, x, y, 10, 10);
  }

  //checks if it hit the target, but does a little bit of rounding because the sprite is big
  //done this way in the interest of realism
  public boolean hitTarget(){
    if(target != null){
      if(abs(x - target.getCenterX()) <= 5 && abs(y - target.getCenterY()) <= 5 ){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
    //this activates if the target is null, which marks this for deletion
    return true;
  }
}
```

I've been researching this for hours and realized my approach was unnecessarily complicated when I was looking into converting floats into strings, formatting them to some number of decimal places, then trying to convert that into a fraction which I would then reduce.  I feel like this is far easier than I realize, but I am lacking the math background to do it.  All necessary changes should only need to be done in Projectile.update().  Thanks!

Comment: Quirliom got what I needed, I'll accept his answer in 6 minutes when Stack Overflow lets me.  Thanks for taking a look at it though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want your projectile to 'track' the target, then you can use a simple bit of trig to work out the relative speeds in x and y:

```
//Calculate the differences in position
float diffX = target.getCenterX() - this.x;
float diffY = target.getCenterY() - this.y;

//Calculate the angle
double angle = Math.atan2(diffY, diffX);

//Update the positions
x += Math.cos(angle) * speed;
y += Math.sin(angle) * speed;
```

This essentially calculates the angle between the projectile and the target, then moves the projectile in that direction, based on the speed given.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed.  Thanks, I really have to brush up on my trig apparently...

Comment: I'm trying, Stack Overflow says I need to wait another 5 minutes

Comment: Just a note, as per the Processing API, you don't need to import the Java Math class, as Processing already provides functions (that are wrappers of the Math class) for atan(), cos() and sin() ... http://processing.org/reference/atan_.html http://processing.org/reference/cos_.html http://processing.org/reference/sin_.html